# How to ask Yes/No questions using FormFlow?

Tags: botframework

I just can't figure out how to ask a yes/no question while filling a form with FormFlow. You can't use the Confirm method to fill a bool,

```
var builtForm = new FormBuilder<BuyingACar>()
            .Field(nameof(NewCar))
            .Field(nameof(Model))
            .Field(nameof(Brand))
            .Build();
```

I need the field "NewCar" to be a prompt with buttons "yes" and "no". I don't want to use an enum since it will send a 0/1 when a button's pressed.

edit: My final goal is to fill a bool field.

Comment: What's the issue? Please post the code of the BuyingACar model

Comment: @EzequielJadib the issue is that FormFlow does not support bools. I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: Have you tried using it and it didn't work or your comment is based on the documentation? I'm seeing there is recognizer for booleans: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/Field.cs#L701 & https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/Recognize.cs#L460

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work perfecly with booleans. It accepts "Yes", "No", "y" and "n" as possible answers. If you use the special [Pattern Language](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html#patterns) {||} you can edit the prompt to include the options.
Here is an example.

```
public enum Brands
{
    Volvo, BMW
}

[Serializable]
public class BuyingACar
{
    [Prompt("Would you like to buy a car? {||}")]
    public bool NewCar { get; set; }
    public Brands? Brand { get; set; }

    public static IForm<BuyingACar> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<BuyingACar>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No buttons yes/no buttons, though.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You just need to use the special Pattern Language to add the options.